# Media queries not acting how I would like on iPhone

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm fairly new to using media queries and i'm probably missing something obvious but I've had a look around stack overflow and haven't yet found my solution.

Also to note, I'm using an old phone (iPhone 4S) on Chrome browser to view my site.

When I view the site on my mobile it's the exact same as if I was to view it on my browser and hasn't took my media queries into account as the browser does when I resize it.

Note the first image is how it currently looks, I want it to look like the second image

[image: Phone & Unresized browser view]

[image: How it should look on an iPhone]

I'll try to include the relevant code:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

Media queries:

```
@media all and (max-width: 701px) {
.quote {
    width: 550px;
}
}

@media all and (max-width: 551px) {
.quote {
    width: 400px;
    bottom: 325px;
}

nav { display: none }

header {
    width: 100%;
}
.title {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #2d2d2d;
}

.quote span { color: #2d2d2d; }
.explore span { color: #2d2d2d; }

.explore {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #2d2d2d;
}


body {
    background-image: url("http://htc-wallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Mountain1.jpg?8a4edc");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

}

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> this is already enough

Comment: if you use Safari on your phone how is it then?

Comment: please check all bracket are closed in media queries second media queries must be on bottom

Answer (score 0):

I think it has. It's the font size you need to have changed. I believe some mobile devices automatically adjust your font, but it may be something you don't want. Try this:

```
-ms-text-size-adjust: none;
-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
```

Let me know if that answers your question.

Comment: if it "has". Then surely the view on my iPhone would be similar to the second image shown above, and not the first one - Meaning the background image would have changed

Comment: Okay you weren't clear on the images. You should have mentioned that the second image was in fact the correct one, instead of your current mobile view. If you haven't tried already, try the chrome dev tools and select a comparable phone to try under the mobile devices icon. It can simulate the display on your phone, but not perfectly. Is the outcome the same there?

Comment: I've tried using the Chrome dev tools but they're just so inaccurate. It simulates the site using media queries, but when I actually use the iPhne to view the website; it doesn't show the site correctly, not rendering the media queries

Comment: Can you show a comparable portrait view screenshot? It's hard to see what exactly is happening when you're giving us a landscape view and telling us that you want it to look like the second image in a portrait view.